# Datatables URL parameter filtering

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, datatables

Is there a way to grab a URL parameter and push it into `datatables` as a filter query?

ie. `datatable.cfm/?sSearch_6=overdue`

This would hopefully search column 6 for matches for "overdue"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using code similar to this [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/development/server-side/coldfusion) example.

You could try something like this:

```
<!--- 
    Filter Column 6
 --->
<cfparam name="url.sSearch_6" default="" type="string" />


<!--- Data set after filtering --->
<cfquery datasource="#coldfusionDatasource#" name="qFiltered">
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS #listColumns#
        FROM #sTableName# 
    <cfif len(trim(url.sSearch))>
        WHERE <cfloop list="#listColumns#" index="thisColumn"><cfif thisColumn neq listFirst(listColumns)> OR </cfif>#thisColumn# LIKE <cfif thisColumn is "version"><!--- special case ---><cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_FLOAT" value="#val(url.sSearch)#" /><cfelse><cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="%#trim(url.sSearch)#%" /></cfif></cfloop>
        <cfif len(trim(url.sSearch_6))>
            AND #ListGetAt(listColumns,6)# = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#url.sSearch_6#" />
        </cfif>
    </cfif>

    <!--- Filter Column 6 --->
    <cfif url.iSortingCols gt 0>
        ORDER BY <cfloop from="0" to="#url.iSortingCols-1#" index="thisS"><cfif thisS is not 0>, </cfif>#listGetAt(listColumns,(url["iSortCol_"&thisS]+1))# <cfif listFindNoCase("asc,desc",url["sSortDir_"&thisS]) gt 0>#url["sSortDir_"&thisS]#</cfif> </cfloop>
    </cfif>

</cfquery>
```

Comment: Micah,
Thanks. I am able to successfully push searches through to the handler, but I would like to direct to the datatables page with a parameter and have the page parse the parameter and forward it to the handler. Allen on datatables suggested `aoSearchCols`. I am looking into it now.